# #vb.net ¿Cómo corrijo el siguiente error?

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código en *vb.net* y quiero subir un archivo a una carpeta dentro de una carpeta, pero en si no es un error, solo que creo que mi lógica está mal. Creo una carpeta dentro de una carpeta pero el archivo no lo guarda dentro de la 2da carpeta

```
 Dim comando As New SqlCommand()
        Dim idarea As Integer
        idarea = Request.Cookies("cook_usuario_evaluacion")("cook_idarea_usuario_evaluacion")
        ' idarea = Label7.Text
        Label7.Text = idarea
        Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("Evidencia/e") + Trim(Str(idarea))
        'Comprueba si el directorio existe.
        If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
            'If Directorio (Carpeta) no existe. Crearla.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
        End If
        'Guarda el archivo en el directorio (carpeta).
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName))
        'Muestra el mensaje de exito.
        mensaje1.Text = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName) + " Archivo cargado."
```

[image: referencia al codigo]
**la variable Trim(Str(idarea)) toma un id que seria el numero que se muestra en la carpeta**

Comment: Prueba dejando el código para la carpeta así:  `Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Evidencia/e") + Trim(Str(idarea))` Me comentas.

Comment: Acabo de utilizar la corrección del código y sigue igual , lo guarda fuera compañero (~/Evidencia/e)

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que si borro + Trim(Str(idarea)) si me guarda dentro pero no me nombra la carpeta con el id

Comment: Tal vez \ en lugar de /

Comment: me marca un error: No se pudo asignar la ruta de acceso '/Evidencia/e/'.

Comment: `Server.MapPath("~/Evidencia/e/") + Trim(Str(idarea))` Prueba de esta manera

Comment: disculpen la tardanza @harifo Acabo de actualizar con el consejo que me dices, y sigue en la misma no guarda dentro le archivo

Comment: ya hace tiempo encontre como a qui el resultado:
        folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Evidencia/e" + Trim(Str(idarea)) + "/")

Answer (score 0):

No le has puesto la contra-barra a la dirección de la nueva carpeta secundaria ni tampoco esta bien declarado el caso de pregunta si existe el directorio...
Resuelve-lo así:

```
    Dim comando As New SqlCommand()
    Dim idarea As Integer
    idarea = Request.Cookies("cook_usuario_evaluacion")("cook_idarea_usuario_evaluacion")
    ' idarea = Label7.Text
    Label7.Text = idarea
    Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("Evidencia/e") + Trim(Str(idarea))
    'Comprueba si el directorio existe.
    If Directory.Exists(folderPath) = False Then
        'If Directorio (Carpeta) no existe. Crearla.
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    'Guarda el archivo en el directorio (carpeta).
    If Strings.Right(folderPath, 1) = "\" Then
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName))
    Else
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath & "\" & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName))
    End If
    'Muestra el mensaje de exito.
    mensaje1.Text = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName) + " Archivo cargado."
```